# Зачем нужен тип long когда есть int?

Tags: c, типы

В *С* есть тип `long`. Согласно: [Wiki c-types](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B2_C) он занимет в памяти 4 байта, да и диапазон значений у него такой же как и у `int`.
Тогда зачем он нужен?

Выписка из wiki:

`int`:

> Основной тип целого числа со знаком. Может содержать числа в диапазоне
>   [−32767, +32767]. range;[3][4] Таким образом, это по крайней мере 16
>   бит (2 байта). На практике, во всех современных компиляторах имеет
>   размер в 4 байта и диапазон [-2147483648, +2147483647]

`long`:

> Тип длинного целого числа со знаком. Может содержать числа, как
>   минимум, в диапазоне [−2 147 483 647, +2 147 483 647].[3][4] Таким
>   образом, это по крайней мере 32 бита (4 байта).

Comment: На практике long чаще всего вдвое больше int. Стандарт гарантирует, что не меньше, но не запрещает быть больше.

Comment: @free_ze "чаще всего" - это когда? :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov очевидно, что на распространенных пользовательских платформах, которые средний по больнице Вася встречает чаще всего)

Comment: Выходит его создали чтобы писать код можно было оптимальнее, когда на устройстве мало места и тебе очень важен размер переменных. То есть это с древних времен перешло к нам?

Comment: @free_ze это какие - распространенные пользовательские?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Вас научить гуглить рейтинги?)

Comment: @free_ze нет. Надо просто перечислить конкретные пары из платформы и компилятора.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Никто не будет против, если вы дополните мой комментарий своими примерами. К чему же этот флуд?

Comment: Скорее, зачем нужен int, когда есть short и long

Comment: @free_ze, `очевидно, что на распространенных пользовательских платформах, которые средний по больнице Вася встречает чаще всего` -- не, не на распространенных пользовательских, а на  **правильных** (а наиболее распространенная винда к ним не относится)

Comment: @avp не могли бы вы подробнее раскрыть тему этих правил? И почему винды в этом случае неправильные?

Comment: @free_ze, а что тут раскрывать? \*nix -- правильные -).

Comment: Термин "платформа" в терминологии языка С/С++ является синонимом терминов "реализация"/"компилятор". Размеры типов физически определяются только компилятором, и могут, при желании, выбираться с полным игнорированием параметров хардверной платформы. Игнорировать параметры машины в С/С++ не принято, но никаких формальных преград этому нет.

Comment: @avp ...а бог сидит на небе, верно?)

Comment: @free_ze, будучи агностиком, вполне могу это допустить. / Что же касается винды (я не ошибся, вас именно это мучает?), то не опускаясь (поднимаясь?) до глубин архитектуры систем, пожалуйста, один небольшой пример -- программа, запущенная из cmd получает аргументы командной строки в кодировке cp1251, а stdin с терминалом в cp866.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Процессоры развивались постепенно все более расширяя емкость регистров. Например, ранее в `DOS` тип `int` соответствовал 16 разрядному целочисленному значению, так как на IBM-совместимых компьютеров регистры были 16-разрядными. Например, регистр `AX` является 16 разрядным, а его подрегистры `AL` и `AH` имели разрядность равную 8 битам. До этого вообще регистры процессоров были 8 разрядными.

Если выполнить, допустим, умножение двух объектов 16-разрядного типа `int`, то для хранения результата нужно использовать два регистра как, например, регистры `AX` и `DX`. Для этого результата уже нужно вводить новый целочисленный тип. И такой тип был введен. Это тип `long` .

Затем появились 64-разрядные процессоры. Необходимо различать 16-разрядные целые числа, 32-разрядные целые числа и 64- разрядные целые числа. Поэтому был введен дополнительный целый тип `Long long`. Имейте в виду, что нужно было сохранять обратную совместимость с целыми типами, введенными ранее для процессоров с меньшей разрядностью.

Поэтому в стандарте C принято, что

```
sizeof( short ) <= sizeof( int )
sizeof( int ) <= sizeof( long )
sizeof( long ) <= sizeof( long long )
```

У разработчиков компиляторов есть свобода выбора, какая разрядность будет у типа `long` и других целочисленных типов. Например, разрядность типа `long` может составлять не `32 бита, а 64 бита.

Чтобы программы были переносимы, возникла необходимость вводить новые типы со строго указанной разрядностью такие, как, например, int_least32_t или int32_t.

На одних 64-битовых платформах тип `long` и тип `long long` могут иметь 64-битовуж разрядность. На других 64-битовых платформах тип `long` может быть 32-битовым и тип `int` также может быть 32-битовым, а тип `long long` - 64 битовым.

Тем не менее ранг типа `long long` больше ранга типа `long`, а тип `long` в свою очередь имеет ранг выше, чем тип `int`.

На этом основываются правила преобразования типов в выражениях. Например, если тип `long` и тип `int` имеют разрядность равную 32 битам, то в следующем фрагменте кода

```
long x = 0;
unsigned int y = 0;

x + y;
```

тип выражения `x + y` имеет тип `unsigned long`.

В связи с этим имеются некоторые курьезы, связанные с такими преобразованиями особенно при выборе перегруженной функции в C++.

Один из таких примеров описан в следующей [теме](http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-3-0-00000047-000-10001-0-1486983554), где ближе к ее концу (можно быстро найти это сообщение по ключевому слову `int64_t`)  описывается один из таких курьезов, связанных с вызовом перегруженной функции, у которой параметр имеет тип `std::int64_t`, который, как оказалось, является не алиасом типа `long long int`, а алиасом типа `long int`, который на данной платформе является 64-битовым.

Answer (score 19):

Размеры типов `int` и `long` не регламентированы Стандартом языка. Но регламентировано отношение их размеров, т.е. `sizeof(int)` <= `sizeof(long)`.

На текущий момент можно сказать, что размер `long` зависит как от [разрядности процессора, так и от используемой ОС](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/size-of-long-integer-type-on-different-architecture-and-os). Например, для Linux и MacOS он будет 8 байт для 64bit архитектур, и 4 байта для 32bit архитектур. В Windows размер будет 4 байта, независимо от разрядности архитектуры.

Например, в Стандарте С++ даже встречается такой пример:

```
static_assert(sizeof(long) >= 8, "64-bit code generation required for this library.");
```

Использовать разные типы можно, например, для обеспечения перегрузки функций:

```
void f(int) {}
void f(long) {}
f(42); // int
f(42L); // long
```

Также не стоит забывать, что данные типы имеют разный ранг (integer conversion rank), что влияет на правила преобразования целочисленных типов.

Уточнение по поводу размеров `long` после комментариев [@AnT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/182825/ant) со [страницы cygwin](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/programming.html#gcc-64):

> While the Mingw and Microsoft compilers use the LLP64 data model, Cygwin compilers use the LP64 data model, just like Linux. This affects the size of the type long. In the LLP64 model preferred by Microsoft, **sizeof(long) is 4**. This applies for the related Win32 types like LONG, ULONG, DWORD, etc., too.
>
> In the LP64 model used by Cygwin, **sizeof(long) is 8**, just like the size of pointers or the types size_t/ssize_t. This simplifies porting Linux applications to 64 bit Cygwin, but it requires due diligence when calling Windows functions taking LONG, ULONG, DWORD, or any other equivalent type. This is especially important in conjunction with pointers.

Comment: Ответ вводит в заблуждение. Размер целого С/С++ типа не зависит от используемой ОС вообще никак. Размер типа зависит только от компилятора и больше ни от чего. Компилятор, разумеется, в вопросах выбора размера типа будет руководствоваться сображениями эффективности, что привнесет сюда и учтение разрядности процессора. Так что разрядность процессора *косвенно/опосредованно* влияет. Точнее, не "влияет", а скажем, "снисходительно/необязательно учитывается" при принятии таких решений. Кроме компилятора на размер типа не влияет больше ничто.

Comment: @AnT мы же не о сферических конях в вакууме тут беседуем. Да и не сам я это придумал, и даже ссылку добавил. Плюс пример из вполне настоящего Стандарта.

Comment: При чем здесь сферические кони? Нет никаких причин типу `long` быть 4 байта "на Windows". Более того, это утверждение соврешено не верно: в компиляторе MSVC на Windows `long` - 4 байта, в компиляторе GCC на Windows `long` - 8 байт. Так что Windows тут никакой роли не играет. Это вопрос решения авторов компилятора, котрое зависит от соврешенно иных причин. Да и тот факт, что в 64-битном мире тип `int` не стал 64-битным (как рекомендуют стандарты С и С++) практически ни в одном компиляторе говорит о том, что вопросы обратной совместимости играют бОльшую роль, чем разрядность процессора.

Comment: @AnT *"в компиляторе GCC на Windows long - 8 байт."* Я вот поставил [MinGW-w64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) и тестовый код говорит, что `sizeof(long) == 4` для 64bit окружения. ОС Win7.

Comment: А я вот поставил Cygwin и тестовый код говорит, что `sizeof(long) == 8`. Ваш MinGW, очевидно, эмулирует поведение MSVC для совместимости с его билиотеками.

Answer (score 6):

Тип `long` не "занимает в памяти 4 байта". Он занимает *как минимум 32 бита*, т.е. имеет диапазон как минимум `[−2147483647, +2147483647]`. А сверху его размер не ограничен.

Тип `int` занимает как минимум 16 бит, ибо имеет диапазон как минимум `[−32767, +32767]` (как вы сами заметили).

Поэтому не совсем ясно, откуда вы взяли предположение об одинаковости диапазонов этих типов - уже из процитированного вами видно, что они запросто могут быть разными.

В языке С++ система целочисленных типов обладает тем свойством, что

```
sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)
```

т.е. вполне возможно что размеры (и диапазоны) этих типов все будут различными.

В языке С, по каким-то историческим причинам, это соотношение определяется как

```
диапазон(signed char) ⊆ диапазон(short) ⊆ диапазон(int) ⊆ диапазон(long) ⊆ диапазон(long long)
```

Но идея, понятное дело, в обоих случаях одна и та же. И все эти типы могут быть различными с точки зрения диапазона. Как, впрочем, все они могу быть и одинаковыми с точки зрения размера и диапазона.

То, что у вас на какой то платформе тип `long` совпал по представлению с типом `int` является лишь особенностью вашей платформы.

Comment: short может быть 1 байт?

Comment: @alexolut: Разумеется, может быть. Но еще раз: речь идет о C-байте, то есть об байте типа `char`. А этот C-байт имеет право содержать сколько угодно бит. Например, на платформах для микроконтроллеров  Texas Instruments TMS320C28x `CHAR_BIT == 16` и `sizeof(char) == sizeof(short) == sizeof(int) == 1`. То есть и `short` и даже `int` занимают 1 байт. Только это 16-битный байт. См. например https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/c2000/f/171/t/21671

Comment: Интересно, а есть ли сейчас архитектуры, где размеры всех упомянутых стандартных типов различны?

Comment: @alexolut, похоже [RISC-V](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31911994/7286264), но что из 128-бит варианта реализовано в железе, не знаю.

Comment: Кол-во значений в интервале [−2147483647, +2147483647] (в открытом или закрытом) нечетное, что не стыкуется с двоичной системой счисления (в которой при любом кол-ве бит, кол-во значений всегда четное): либо одно из значений зарезервировано (запрещено), либо два значения обозначают одно число). Не могли бы вы подробнее этот момент объяснить.

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian: `[−2147483647, +2147483647]` - это *гарантированный* интервал. Но никто не запрещает нам сделать его ассиметричным - `[−2147483648, +2147483647]`, как это и делается в наших повседневных платформах с дополнительным кодом. В результате не надо никаких "зарезервированых значений" или "два значения обозначают одно число".

Comment: @AnT нет под рукой ссылки на стандарт? Листал, пока не нашел.

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian: Сссылки про что именно?

Comment: @AnT где в стандарте гарантируется этот (`[−2147483647, +2147483647]`) интервал для `long`.

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian: В разделе 3.9.1/3 стандарта С++ (С++14) говорится, что к целочисленным типам в С++ применяются все требования из раздела 5.2.4.2.1 стандарта С. А уж в 5.2.4.2.1 стандарта С сказано, что значение `LONG_MIN` должно быть `-2147483647` или меньше, а значение `LONG_MAX` должно быть `+2147483647` или больше.

Comment: @AnT то же нашел уже, спасибо большое

Comment: @AnT, "_В языке С++ система целочисленных типов обладает тем свойством, что `sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int)`_". Мне вот интересно, а возможна ли такая ситуация: и `short`, и `int` оба 32-битные; у типа `short` все биты участвуют в представлении значения, но у типа `int` только (15 + 1) бит кодируют числа, а остальные 16 являются padding bits?

Answer (score 4):

Язык C предлагает Вам множество типов. В частности гарантированно, что int не больше long. А long не больше long long. Вы выбираете по своим нуждам и удобству.

Когда тип используются часто, то компилятор оптимизирует работу с ним. После оптимизации в компиляторе, начинают рекомендовать использование типа для каких-то целей.

На разных архитектурах ЭВМ разные размеры регистров процессора, но соотношение размеров типов сохраняется.

Простыми словами: часто использовали int в программах, поэтому его вытянули под размер 4 байта на PC, что соответствует регистру процессора x32. long не стали вытягивать до 8 байт, потому что на x32 потребуется две команды процессору вместо одной. Но не удалять же long, ведь его используют какие-то программы.