# Есть ли отличия size_t от SIZE_T?

Tags: c++, winapi, кроссплатформенность

До сих пор везде использовал `size_t`, считая что это целочисленный тип, который адаптируется под  разрядность операционной системы (4 байта - для x86, 8 - для x64). И вот для работы с `WriteProcessMemory` я так же пытался использовать `size_t*` в качестве последнего аргумента `SIZE_T  *lpNumberOfBytesWritten` - на что получил:

> ```
> invalid conversion from 'size_t*' to 'SIZE_T*'
> ```

Перейдя к typedef-ам я обнаружил следующее для SIZE_T:

```
typedef ULONG_PTR SIZE_T, *PSIZE_T;
typedef  unsigned long ULONG_PTR, *PULONG_PTR;
```

причем последняя строка была внутри какого-то `#if` с комментарием

> ```
> /*  !_WIN64 */
> ```

и следующее для `size_t`:

```
typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ size_t;
```

где `__SIZE_TYPE__` , видимо, какой-то макрос (автопереход к нему у меня не работает).

Правильно я понимаю, что они по сути своей идентичны и не зря имеют одинаковое именование, а эта ошибка - лишь формальность, вызванная различием их реализаций?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, о какой именно "сути" вы говорите. Можно сказать что "по сути" все целочисленные типы "идентичны" - в большинстве своих применений они что-то подсчитывают, хранят некое количество. Но какая польза от этого? Полученная вами ошибка говорит, что типы - разные.

Comment: @Ant, я про размерность типов: она может отличаться на разных платформах

Comment: В данном случае она запросто может отличаться. WinAPI завело свой собственный тип `SIZE_T` *именно* для того, чтобы отвязать его характеристики (в том числе размер) от языкового `std::size_t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На моём экземпляре Visual Studio 2017 следующий код даёт такой вывод при различной разрядности проекта:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <BaseTsd.h>
#include <cstddef>

int main()
{
    std::cout << typeid(SIZE_T).name() << "\n" << 
                 typeid(size_t).name() << "\n";
}
```

- 32 bit

  ```
  unsigned long
  unsigned int
  ```
- 64 bit

  ```
  unsigned __int64
  unsigned __int64
  ```

Можно заметить, что на 64 разрядной платформе эти типы идентичны. В то же время на 32 разрядной типы хоть и различны (с точки зрения языка), но представляют одинаковый набор возможных значений, т.е. `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)` в Windows, хотя в общем случае это [не всегда так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/627721/176217). Но даже несмотря на совпадение размеров различные типы не всегда совместимы (иначе бы не было ошибки, с которой вы сюда пришли). И, например, следующий код будет корректным для x86, но вызовет ошибку компиляции для x64:

```
void f(size_t) {}
void f(SIZE_T) {}
```

Если же посмотреть на описание типов, то можно увидеть следующее:

- [SIZE_T](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog/windows-data-types#size-t)

  > The maximum number of bytes to which a pointer can point. Use for a count that must span the full range of a pointer.
  >
  > This type is declared in BaseTsd.h as follows:
  >
  > ```
  > typedef ULONG_PTR SIZE_T;
  > ```
- [size_t](http://eel.is/c++draft/support.types#layout-3)

  > The type `size_­t` is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object ([expr.sizeof]).

По сути, разными словами выражено одно и то же - "тип, позволяющий хранить размер максимально возможного объекта". При этом для `size_t` беззнаковость указана явно, а вот для `SIZE_T` она лишь косвенно проскакивает через букву `U` в `ULONG_PTR`.

Общий совет такой: если работаете с WinAPI и имеется параметр типа `SIZE_T`, то этот тип и стоит использовать, во всех остальных ситуациях - следует отдавать предпочтение стандартным типам C++ для увеличения уровня переносимости кода. Понятно, что на стыке двух миров придётся обеспечивать преобразование одного типа в другой. В хорошем решении этой задачи стык этот должен быть достаточно лаконичен и не размазан по всему коду.

Answer (score 2):

> Правильно я понимаю, что они по сути своей идентичны и незря имеют одинаковое именование, а эта ошибка - лишь формальность, вызванная различием их реализаций?

Да, они должны быть эквивалентны. (В том смысле, что оба беззнаковые, одинакового размера.)

`size_t` (или `std::size_t`) - это стандартный тип из `<cstddef>`/`<stddef.h>`. В своем коде лучше использовать именно его.

`SIZE_T` - тип из WinAPI.

А тип `__SIZE_TYPE__` скорее всего встроен в ваш компилятор, поэтому ваша IDE и не может показать его определение.

Comment: Строго говоря, одинаковость размеров не гарантируется (главное, чтобы смогли поместиться максимально возможные значения), и беззнаковость для WinAPI довольно косвенно упоминается (см.мой ответ).